# How to create a Custom User in strapi.js

Tags: strapi, koa

I am working on a strapi-app and I have 3 content-types:

- User (the one that comes with strapi)
- profile
- Employee (has one User, has one Profile)

This is my code:

```
async create(data, { files } = {}) {
    const profileObj = data.profile
    const employeeObj = {
        salary_type: data.salarytype,
        salary: data.salary
    }
    const userObj = data.user
    profileObj.address = data.address

    const user = await strapi.query('user').create(userObj);
    const profile = await strapi.query('profile').create(profileObj);
    const employee = await strapi.query('employee').create(employeeObj);
    employee.user = user
    employee.profile = profile

    if (files) {
      // automatically uploads the files based on the entry and the model
      await strapi.entityService.uploadFiles(employee, files, {
        model: 'profile',
      });
      return this.findOne({ id: employee.id });
    }

    return employee;
  },
```

It's working but I created another user Controller/service and model because when I tried without creating a new user C/S/M it gave me an error.

Why? Suggestions please.

Answer (score 1):

[Refer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62641454/8002326)
The create user query should be like this.

```
const user = await strapi.query('user', 'users-permissions').create(userObj);
```

This way you need not create a new User API and use the one that comes with Strapi.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const res = await strapi.entityService.create(
        'plugin::users-permissions.user',
        {
          data: {
            username: 'your-username',
            email: "email@",
            provider: 'local',
            blocked: false,
            password: 'raw-password',
            role: 3,
          },
        }
      );
```